# How to pass date parameter from ssrs report to query.commandtext as sql query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdl

I am trying to set an expression for command text like this:

```
="Database.dbo.pPROC 'FirstParameter', " + IIf(Parameters!Date.Value="","null", CDate(Parameters!Date.Value) )
```

and as a second parameter i need to pass **Date/Time** parameter from my report `(Parameters!Date.Value)` to execute procedure. 
The second parameter in sql has a `smalldatetimeformat (f.e 2018-08-01 00:00:00)`.

Command works when I do not choose date (null) but when I want to choose date in report I have got an error as output:

> "Error during processing of the CommandText expression of dataset
>   ...."

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't make things too complicated.

Instead of building a expression for the command text, chose **Stored Procedure** as the *Query type*. On the **Parameters** page of the *Properties* window, you can map the parameters of the stored procedure to report parameters or expressions.